# How to fine the range of a number?

Tags: vba

The valid range of a *Byte* variable is `0` and `255`.

```
Dim b As Byte
b = 30
' The following statement causes an error because the value is too large. 
'b = 256
```

how to find the range of a number like `30 = 256`

Comment: Numbers don't have ranges. Variables/data types do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [documentation for data types in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/47zceaw7(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

The documentation explicitly states the valid ranges for all data types.